# GDPR & CCPA compliance involving terms of service violation

Tags: gdpr, terms-of-service, eula, ccpa

If a user writes a comment on a website that gets flagged and removed+archived are we still obligated to delete the user content and/or the association of that comment with the person? According to GDPR and CCPA are we obligated to delete/disassociate user created content even if the user has violated the terms of service?

Wouldn't it be disadvantageous legally speaking if a user later on opened a law suit and we had no record of our interactions with that individual because we deleted their content in order to comply with these laws?

Answer (score 1):

### Why do you think you are required to delete it?

For example [Article 7](https://gdpr-info.eu/art-17-gdpr/) of the GDPR has an exemption (among many others):

> for the establishment, exercise or defence of legal claims.

Comment: Plus the service or website has a legitimate interest in maintaining records for the purposes of monitoring abuse of the service.

Comment: Does the same apply for CCPA?

Comment: similar clause in ccpa: 1798.145.a.d "  (a) The obligations imposed on businesses by this title shall not restrict a business’ ability to: ... (4) Exercise or defend legal claims."